How can i send either tf or fixed frame data from a gazebo ignition fortress world to rviz2 through a parameter bridge?
Every possible solution that i could find by searching was for ros1 rviz1 and gazebo classic, which results in it not working for me. I've a virtual intel realsense D435 camera kept on a cube in a gazebo ignition fortress world. I need to transfer point cloud data to ros2 rviz2 with a parameter bridge but i can't do that without either tf or fixed frame data. I get errors when i try to use the parameter bridge for transferring pose data. I don't get any options listed on clicking the fixed frame dropdown box in ros2 rviz2. Whatever that i enter manually as a name for the fixed frame results in errors. The commands and screenshots are shared below for reference.
Terminals commands.
root@LAPTOP-GL67113F:~/ws/src# ros2 topic list
/clicked_point
/goal_pose
/initialpose
/parameter_events
/rgbd_camera/camera_info
/rgbd_camera/depth_image
/rgbd_camera/image
/rgbd_camera/points
/rosout
/tf
/tf_static
root@LAPTOP-GL67113F:~/ws/src# ign topic -l
/clock
/gazebo/resource_paths
/gui/camera/pose
/gui/record_video/stats
/model/Intel-RealSense-D435_openrobotics/pose
/model/Intel-RealSense-D435_openrobotics/pose_static
/rgbd_camera/camera_info
/rgbd_camera/depth_image
/rgbd_camera/image
/rgbd_camera/points
/sensors/marker
/stats
/world/sensor_world/clock
/world/sensor_world/dynamic_pose/info
/world/sensor_world/model/Intel-RealSense-D435_openrobotics/joint_state
/world/sensor_world/pose/info
/world/sensor_world/scene/deletion
/world/sensor_world/scene/info
/world/sensor_world/state
/world/sensor_world/stats
root@LAPTOP-GL67113F:~/ws/src# 

Terminal warnings/errors.
root@LAPTOP-GL67113F:~/ws/src# ros2 run ros_gz_bridge parameter_bridge /rgbd_camera/image@sensor_msgs/msg/Image@gz.msgs.Image /rgbd_camera/camera_info@sensor_msgs/msg/CameraInfo@gz.msgs.CameraInfo /rgbd_camera/depth_image@sensor_msgs/msg/Image@gz.msgs.Image /rgbd_camera/points@sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2@gz.msgs.PointCloudPacked /model/Intel-RealSense-D435_openrobotics/pose@tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage@ignition::msgs::Pose_V
[INFO] [1718108902.576318818] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/image (gz.msgs.Image) -> /rgbd_camera/image (sensor_msgs/msg/Image)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1718108902.577222366] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/image (sensor_msgs/msg/Image) -> /rgbd_camera/image (gz.msgs.Image)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1718108902.577741388] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/camera_info (gz.msgs.CameraInfo) -> /rgbd_camera/camera_info (sensor_msgs/msg/CameraInfo)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1718108902.578049487] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/camera_info (sensor_msgs/msg/CameraInfo) -> /rgbd_camera/camera_info (gz.msgs.CameraInfo)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1718108902.578486573] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/depth_image (gz.msgs.Image) -> /rgbd_camera/depth_image (sensor_msgs/msg/Image)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1718108902.578710361] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/depth_image (sensor_msgs/msg/Image) -> /rgbd_camera/depth_image (gz.msgs.Image)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1718108902.578999775] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/points (gz.msgs.PointCloudPacked) -> /rgbd_camera/points (sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1718108902.579260223] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/points (sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2) -> /rgbd_camera/points (gz.msgs.PointCloudPacked)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1718108902.579695986] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/model/Intel-RealSense-D435_openrobotics/pose (ignition::msgs::Pose_V) -> /model/Intel-RealSense-D435_openrobotics/pose (tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage)] (Lazy 0)
[WARN] [1718108902.579765509] [ros_gz_bridge]: Failed to create a bridge for topic [/model/Intel-RealSense-D435_openrobotics/pose] with ROS2 type [tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage] to topic [/model/Intel-RealSense-D435_openrobotics/pose] with Gazebo Transport type [ignition::msgs::Pose_V]
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ros2 run ros_gz_bridge parameter_bridge /rgbd_camera/image@sensor_msgs/msg/Image@gz.msgs.Image /rgbd_camera/camera_info@sensor_msgs/msg/CameraInfo@gz.msgs.CameraInfo /rgbd_camera/depth_image@sensor_msgs/msg/Image@gz.msgs.Image /rgbd_camera/points@sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2@gz.msgs.PointCloudPacked /model/Intel-RealSense-D435_openrobotics/pose@tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage@ignition::msgs::Pose_V
root@LAPTOP-GL67113F:~/ws/src# ros2 run ros_gz_bridge parameter_bridge /rgbd_camera/image@sensor_msgs/msg/Image@gz.msgs.Image /rgbd_camera/camera_info@sensor_msgs/msg/CameraInfo@gz.msgs.CameraInfo /rgbd_camera/depth_image@sensor_msgs/msg/Image@gz.msgs.Image /rgbd_camera/points@sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2@gz.msgs.PointCloudPacked /model/Intel-RealSense-D435_openrobotics/pose@tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage@ignition::msgs::Pose  
[INFO] [1718108913.765622946] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/image (gz.msgs.Image) -> /rgbd_camera/image (sensor_msgs/msg/Image)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1718108913.766630022] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/image (sensor_msgs/msg/Image) -> /rgbd_camera/image (gz.msgs.Image)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1718108913.767169162] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/camera_info (gz.msgs.CameraInfo) -> /rgbd_camera/camera_info (sensor_msgs/msg/CameraInfo)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1718108913.767454999] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/camera_info (sensor_msgs/msg/CameraInfo) -> /rgbd_camera/camera_info (gz.msgs.CameraInfo)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1718108913.767867254] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/depth_image (gz.msgs.Image) -> /rgbd_camera/depth_image (sensor_msgs/msg/Image)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1718108913.768094729] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/depth_image (sensor_msgs/msg/Image) -> /rgbd_camera/depth_image (gz.msgs.Image)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1718108913.768337013] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/points (gz.msgs.PointCloudPacked) -> /rgbd_camera/points (sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1718108913.768590237] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/points (sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2) -> /rgbd_camera/points (gz.msgs.PointCloudPacked)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1718108913.769015634] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/model/Intel-RealSense-D435_openrobotics/pose (ignition::msgs::Pose) -> /model/Intel-RealSense-D435_openrobotics/pose (tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage)] (Lazy 0)
[WARN] [1718108913.769084626] [ros_gz_bridge]: Failed to create a bridge for topic [/model/Intel-RealSense-D435_openrobotics/pose] with ROS2 type [tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage] to topic [/model/Intel-RealSense-D435_openrobotics/pose] with Gazebo Transport type [ignition::msgs::Pose]
^Z
[2]+  Stopped                 ros2 run ros_gz_bridge parameter_bridge /rgbd_camera/image@sensor_msgs/msg/Image@gz.msgs.Image /rgbd_camera/camera_info@sensor_msgs/msg/CameraInfo@gz.msgs.CameraInfo /rgbd_camera/depth_image@sensor_msgs/msg/Image@gz.msgs.Image /rgbd_camera/points@sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2@gz.msgs.PointCloudPacked /model/Intel-RealSense-D435_openrobotics/pose@tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage@ignition::msgs::Pose
root@LAPTOP-GL67113F:~/ws/src# ros2 run ros_gz_bridge parameter_bridge /rgbd_camera/image@sensor_msgs/msg/Image@gz.msgs.Image /rgbd_camera/camera_info@sensor_msgs/msg/CameraInfo@gz.msgs.CameraInfo /rgbd_camera/depth_image@sensor_msgs/msg/Image@gz.msgs.Image /rgbd_camera/points@sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2@gz.msgs.PointCloudPacked /model/Intel-RealSense-D435_openrobotics/pose_static@tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage@ignition::msgs::Pose_V
[INFO] [1718110239.214973796] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/image (gz.msgs.Image) -> /rgbd_camera/image (sensor_msgs/msg/Image)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1718110239.217511948] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/image (sensor_msgs/msg/Image) -> /rgbd_camera/image (gz.msgs.Image)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1718110239.218919210] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/camera_info (gz.msgs.CameraInfo) -> /rgbd_camera/camera_info (sensor_msgs/msg/CameraInfo)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1718110239.219411853] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/camera_info (sensor_msgs/msg/CameraInfo) -> /rgbd_camera/camera_info (gz.msgs.CameraInfo)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1718110239.220016785] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/depth_image (gz.msgs.Image) -> /rgbd_camera/depth_image (sensor_msgs/msg/Image)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1718110239.220333030] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/depth_image (sensor_msgs/msg/Image) -> /rgbd_camera/depth_image (gz.msgs.Image)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1718110239.220698379] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/points (gz.msgs.PointCloudPacked) -> /rgbd_camera/points (sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1718110239.221003793] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/points (sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2) -> /rgbd_camera/points (gz.msgs.PointCloudPacked)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1718110239.221587180] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/model/Intel-RealSense-D435_openrobotics/pose_static (ignition::msgs::Pose_V) -> /model/Intel-RealSense-D435_openrobotics/pose_static (tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage)] (Lazy 0)
[WARN] [1718110239.221697802] [ros_gz_bridge]: Failed to create a bridge for topic [/model/Intel-RealSense-D435_openrobotics/pose_static] with ROS2 type [tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage] to topic [/model/Intel-RealSense-D435_openrobotics/pose_static] with Gazebo Transport type [ignition::msgs::Pose_V]
^C[INFO] [1718110241.835337503] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
root@LAPTOP-GL67113F:~/ws/src# ros2 run ros_gz_bridge parameter_bridge /rgbd_camera/image@sensor_msgs/msg/Image@gz.msgs.Image /rgbd_camera/camera_info@sensor_msgs/msg/CameraInfo@gz.msgs.CameraInfo /rgbd_camera/depth_image@sensor_msgs/msg/Image@gz.msgs.Image /rgbd_camera/points@sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2@gz.msgs.PointCloudPacked /model/Intel-RealSense-D435_openrobotics/pose_static@tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage@ignition::msgs::Pose  
[INFO] [1718110244.724312552] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/image (gz.msgs.Image) -> /rgbd_camera/image (sensor_msgs/msg/Image)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1718110244.725386086] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/image (sensor_msgs/msg/Image) -> /rgbd_camera/image (gz.msgs.Image)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1718110244.725927000] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/camera_info (gz.msgs.CameraInfo) -> /rgbd_camera/camera_info (sensor_msgs/msg/CameraInfo)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1718110244.726266129] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/camera_info (sensor_msgs/msg/CameraInfo) -> /rgbd_camera/camera_info (gz.msgs.CameraInfo)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1718110244.726754203] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/depth_image (gz.msgs.Image) -> /rgbd_camera/depth_image (sensor_msgs/msg/Image)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1718110244.727001155] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/depth_image (sensor_msgs/msg/Image) -> /rgbd_camera/depth_image (gz.msgs.Image)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1718110244.727352628] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/points (gz.msgs.PointCloudPacked) -> /rgbd_camera/points (sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1718110244.727715141] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/rgbd_camera/points (sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2) -> /rgbd_camera/points (gz.msgs.PointCloudPacked)] (Lazy 0)
[INFO] [1718110244.728172458] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/model/Intel-RealSense-D435_openrobotics/pose_static (ignition::msgs::Pose) -> /model/Intel-RealSense-D435_openrobotics/pose_static (tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage)] (Lazy 0)
[WARN] [1718110244.728280044] [ros_gz_bridge]: Failed to create a bridge for topic [/model/Intel-RealSense-D435_openrobotics/pose_static] with ROS2 type [tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage] to topic [/model/Intel-RealSense-D435_openrobotics/pose_static] with Gazebo Transport type [ignition::msgs::Pose]
^C[INFO] [1718110250.771017219] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
root@LAPTOP-GL67113F:~/ws/src# 

Screenshots.

EDIT:
More terminal commands.
root@LAPTOP-GL67113F:~/ws/src# gz topic -t /model/Intel-RealSense-D435_openrobotics/pose_static -i
bash: gz: command not found
root@LAPTOP-GL67113F:~/ws/src# ign gazebo topic -t /model/Intel-RealSense-D435_openrobotics/pose_static -i
/root/ws/install/lib/ruby/ignition/cmdgazebo6.rb:330:in `parse': invalid option: -t (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    from /root/ws/install/lib/ruby/ignition/cmdgazebo6.rb:344:in `execute'
    from /root/ws/install/bin/ign:301:in `<main>'
/root/ws/install/lib/ruby/ignition/cmdgazebo6.rb:330:in `parse': invalid option: t (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    from /root/ws/install/lib/ruby/ignition/cmdgazebo6.rb:344:in `execute'
    from /root/ws/install/bin/ign:301:in `<main>'
root@LAPTOP-GL67113F:~/ws/src# ros2 run tf2_tools view_frames
[INFO] [1718189657.747308524] [view_frames]: Listening to tf data for 5.0 seconds...
[INFO] [1718189662.775611570] [view_frames]: Generating graph in frames.pdf file...
[INFO] [1718189662.777597055] [view_frames]: Result:tf2_msgs.srv.FrameGraph_Response(frame_yaml='[]')
root@LAPTOP-GL67113F:~/ws/src# 

More screenshots.

(Can adding at least one joint tag to the SDF model solve my issue?)
(How can i broadcast transform data for models in simulations?)

Could you run ros2 run tf2_tools view_frames and give us a screenshot of the output .pdf?

@EricScöerg the results for your suggested commands are now in the post

Ok. Now the above mentioned command subscribe to tf and tf_static topic and should give you a .pdf of the available transformations between the different frames. Since it's empty, I suggest the node responsible for publishing the transforms is broken. Usually it's a robot_state_publisher/pose_publisher or similar that reads some description (.urdf or .xacro) and publishes the resulting tfs from there. Maybe the .xacro/.urdf is broken, too.

I was finally able to resolve the missing "tf" (transform) issue by adding the code shared below to my python launch files. I was also able to figure out the fixed frame's address by going through the SDF file's hierarchy.
from launch_ros.actions import Node

def generate_launch_description():

    tf = Node(
            package='tf2_ros',
            executable='static_transform_publisher',
            arguments = ['--x', '0', '--y', '0', '--z', '0', '--yaw', '0', '--pitch', '0', '--roll', '0', '--frame-id', 'world', '--child-frame-id', '']
    )

    return LaunchDescription([
        tf
    ])


How did you get the /model/Intel-RealSense-D435_openrobotics/pose_static topic to be published by Gazebo?
The classical plugin is gz-sim-pose-publisher-system but it publishes a gz.msgs.pose, that cannot be bridged to /tf.
Can you write the output of: gz topic -t /model/Intel-RealSense-D435_openrobotics/pose_static -i to have information on this topic?

I used "libignition-gazebo-pose-publisher-system" & "ignition-gazebo-joint-state-publisher-system". I realized just now that there are no joint tags in my sdf model. The output of your suggested command is now included in the post. They seem to be meant for classic gazebo. I modified them a bit to make them work for ignition gazebo. It still resulted in warnings/errors though.

The pose-publisher-system outputs a ign.msgs.pose that is convertible to a geometry_msgs/Pose.
On the opposite it cannot be converted to a tf2_msgs/TFMessage as it is missing some information (e.g. frame names).
On the ROS 2 side, you can easily write a node that subscribes to this pose and publishes the corresponding transform on /tf. A package that does the job is available here:
https://github.com/oKermorgant/pose_to_tf
